# Cannot sign in Google Play store on Bluestacks

Tags: google-play-store, bluestacks

I can't install any apps from Bluestacks because I can't sign into Google Play store. I get this message: "Couldn't sign in. There was a problem connecting to www.google.com."

[image: sign-in error displayed in Bluestacks]

Can't figure out why. My laptop doesn't even have an antivirus. It doesn't give any network error notifications either.

Comment: Bluestacks bases on Virtualbox. What network configuration is set for the Bluestacks virtual machine in the VirtualBox manager?

Comment: How do I check that and what should the configuration be set to?

Comment: Open VirtualBox and open the network settings of the BlueStacks VM configuration in VirtualBox.